# Why cannot I debug (remotely) my Azure WebApi?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-web-api2, remote-debugging

I'm working on WebAPI 2 project with Azure. I have one WebAPI hosted on Azure, but I cannot debug it remotely.

By Visual Studio, I click on Attach Debug (of CloudExplorer panel) like following image:

[image: Attach Debugger command of Visual Studio 2015 Cloud Explorer]

But I obtain the following error:

[image: Cloud Explorer exception]

Other collegue on same project and Visual Studio don't have this error. I've tried to:

- Uninstall / reinstall Cloud Explorer
- Run Visual Studio as Administrator
- Disconnect / reconnect to my subscription by Visual Studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, the version of Cloud Explorer is 1.0.61208.9.

Please can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Have you published in Debug configuration? or Release?

Comment: Hi, I've published in debug mode. My collegue can debug correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try below
Step 1: Switch ON Remote Debugging in the configuration tab for your app and save the settings.
Step2: in the VS server explorer connect to azure subscription and and go to the app and right and attach debugger

[image]